# Jekyll Spaceship Rendering Content Inside Four Backtick Fence

Tags: gitlab, markdown, jekyll, mermaid

I need a fence to keep spaceships out.

In the docs, Tse currently uses these exact statements to display a non-rendered Mermaid.js code block:

`````
````
```mermaid!
pie title Pets adopted by volunteers
  "Dogs" : 386
  "Cats" : 85
  "Rats" : 35
```
````
`````

**Figure#1**

As of today, you can confirm that by visiting 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship/master/README.md

For Tse, the above code correctly renders on his doc page as:

````
```mermaid!
pie title Pets adopted by volunteers
  "Dogs" : 386
  "Cats" : 85
  "Rats" : 35
```
````

**Figure#2**

You can verify by visiting: 
https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship/blob/master/README.md#4-mermaid-usage

Unfortunately, this isn't working for me. When I:

1. create a brand new Jekyll site
2. load it with one of Tse's spaceships
3. put Tse's code from Figure#1 in my index.markdown file

I expect to get results similar to what Tse did as shown in Figure#2.

Instead, my website renders this both locally via "bundle exec jekyll serve" and when hosted on an internal GitLab server...

```
<img class="mermaid" src="https://mermaid.ink/svg/eyJjb2RlIjoicGllIHRpdGxlIFBldHMgYWRvcHRlZCBieSB2b2x1bnRlZXJzXG5cIkRvZ3NcIiA6IDM4NlxuXCJDYXRzXCIgOiA4NVxuXCJSYXRzXCIgOiAzNSIsIm1lcm1haWQiOm51bGx9">
```

See also below picture:
[image]

How do I keep my Jekyll Spaceship from blowing through my four backtick code fence so I can get the same results Tse did?

Answer (score 1):

In GitLab flavoured markdown, you need to indicate the language (in this case `markdown`) after the quadruple back ticks whereas in GitHub flavoured markdown, it may be implied. (See official GitLab documentation on [markdown](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/7d33d259b5008fa3e1dbb9965f6e6d114527d9f9/doc/user/markdown.md#L135) for reference)

`````
````markdown
```mermaid!
pie title Pets adopted by volunteers
  "Dogs" : 386
  "Cats" : 85
  "Rats" : 35
```
````
`````

Also, see [GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#fenced-code-blocks) for more information. The official GitLab Flavored Markdown ([GLFM](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/gitlab_flavored_markdown/specification_guide/)) [spec](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/gitlab_flavored_markdown/specification_guide/) seems to be still work in progress.

Comment: I tried putting the text "markdown" after the opening four backticks but I seemed to still get the same problem. Interestingly, specifying the language in that manner at least seemed to cause the unwanted img tag to be colorized in some cases (LOL). I've been trying to create a *public* example on GitHub or GitLab; unfortunately, both of those public platforms are giving me a hassle.

Comment: The method you describe doesn't work for me. See my source at:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawn-eary/testing-netlify-jekyll-and-mermaid/main/index.markdown
It strangely causes the first mermaid block to render as the unwanted <img> tag text. See rendered result here:
https://reliable-kheer-525ee4.netlify.app/